# How to split one column whith multiples delimiters in multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, split

I have values ​​with the following structure: **string OR string_string.interger**

EX:

```
df<-data.frame(Objs=c("Windows","Door_XYZ.1", "Door_XYY.1", "Chair_XYYU.2" ))
```

| Objs |
| --- |
| Windows |
| Door_XYZ.1 |
| Door_XYY.1 |
| Chair_XYYU.2 |

Using the command split(), separate() or something similar I need to generate a dataframe similar to this one:

Obs: The split must be performed for the characters "_" and "."

| Objs | IND | TAG | Control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | NA | NA | NA |
| Door_XYZ.1 | Door | XYZ | 1 |
| Door_XYY.1 | Door | XYY | 1 |
| Chair_XYYU.2 | Chair | XYYU | 2 |

The closest solution was suggested by @Tommy, in similar context.

```
df %>%  data.frame(.,do.call(rbind,str_split(.$Objs,"_")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the `sep` argument in `separate()` will nearly get the result you need. A conditional mutate was also needed to remove the Windows entry from the IND column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Objs=c("Windows","Door_XYZ.1", "Door_XYY.1", "Chair_XYYU.2" ))

df %>% 
  separate(Objs, into = c("IND", "TAG", "Control"), remove = FALSE, fill = "right") %>% 
  mutate(IND = if_else(Objs == IND, NA_character_, IND))
#>           Objs   IND  TAG Control
#> 1      Windows  <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#> 2   Door_XYZ.1  Door  XYZ       1
#> 3   Door_XYY.1  Door  XYY       1
#> 4 Chair_XYYU.2 Chair XYYU       2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>